# Modal Ajax Failing to Populate

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I'm not sure why this modal isn't populating the post ajax data. Its actually supposed to update a row in my SQL DB upon success but the error I'm getting is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null." Does anyone have any idea why this failing?

Updated: I apologize for leaving out the php which generated the partners item.

HTML:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($partners)) {
 //   $optionsPartners .="<option>" . $row['Partners'] . "</option>";
      $optionsPartners.="<input type='checkbox' name='Partners[]'  value=".$row['Partners']."> ".$row['Partners']."<br>";
 }

$partnersmenu=

    /*"<select name='Partners' id='Partners'>
      " . $optionsPartners . "
    </select>"*/
    $optionsPartners;

?>
   <div id="id02" class="modal">
  <span onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" 
class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
  <!-- Modal Content -->
  <form class="modal-content animate" action="modify_records.php" method="post">

    <div class="container">
       <h3>Edit an Existing Project</h3>
          <label for="Project_Name" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Project Name:</label>
          <input type="Project_Name" name="Project_Name" id="Project_Name" placeholder="Project Name">
          <br><br>
          <label for="Partners" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Partners:</label>
          <?php
          echo $partnersmenu;
          ?>
          <br><br>
  <input type="button" id="edit_button<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class="btn" value="Submit" data-dismiss="modal"  onclick="edit_row('<?php echo $row['id'];?>');">
          <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
    </div> 
    <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['edit_row']))

    {
     $row=$_POST['id'];
     $Project_Name=$_POST['Project_Name'];
     $Partners=$_POST['Partners'];

     mysqli_query($conn,"update Project_Detail set Project_Name='$Project_Name',Partners='$Partners' where id=$row");
     echo "success";
     exit();
    }
```

JS:

```
   function edit_row(id)//save_row(id)
    {
     //var id=document.getElementById("id"+id).value;
     var id=document.getElementById("id"+id);
     var Project_Name=document.getElementById("Project_Name"+id).value;
     var Partners=document.getElementById("Partners"+id).value;
             $.ajax
     ({
      type:'post',
      url:'modify_records.php',
      data:{
       edit_row:'edit_row',
       id:id,
       Project_Name:Project_Name,
       Partners:Partners,
       },
      success:function(response) {
       if(response=="success")
       {

        //document.getElementById("id"+id).innerHTML=id;   
        document.getElementById("Project_Name"+id).innerHTML=Project_Name;
        document.getElementById("Partners"+id).innerHTML=Partners;
        //document.getElementById("edit_button"+id).style.display="block";
       // document.getElementById("save_button"+id).style.display="none";
       }
      },
      error: function(response) {
         alert("some error");
      }
     });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few problems and they all pertain to how you are calling you elements in your javascript and how your elements are labeled in your html.

Example:

```
<input type="Project_Name" name="Project_Name" id="Project_Name" placeholder="Project Name">
```

Should look like this:

```
<input type="text" name="Project_Name" id="Project_Name<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" placeholder="Project Name">
```

Look through all your elements and then look through your js so your are calling the correct ids.

Also in your html I copied in above, I changed the type to "text".

Also,  I do not see an element with the id of "Partners" let alone "Partners" + id.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've updated the included code above. I apologize for the confusion. Also, I really appreciate the help from everyone.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var id=document.getElementById("id");
```

instead of

```
var id=document.getElementById("id"+id);
```